Spark 3.4.1 on Kubernetes: Spark submit ignores flag "--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark"
Spark submit does not take into account the

--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark

flag because the driver pod is in failed state after some minutes of running and the error reads:

Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET at: https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/stream-processing-7b642b932b4c6dda-driver. Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. pods "stream-processing-7b642b932b4c6dda-driver" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default".

If I do kubectl describe sa spark, this is the output:
Name:                spark
Namespace:           default
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              spark-secret
Events:              <none>

spark-secret was created like this:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: spark-secret
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: spark
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token

By describing spark-secret I can find the oauth and the ca.crt required by other --conf in spark-submit.
I have also added the clusterrole like this:
kubectl create clusterrolebinding spark-role --clusterrole=edit --serviceaccount=default:spark --namespace=default

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks!
